# How to read a Chinese txt file (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, utf-8, decode

I have a .txt file named "chinchars.txt". Inside, I have a single line with these two characters:

节日

How do I read this text file and return those to characters? 
Using this code:

```
inputFile = open('chinchars.txt').readlines()
```

It outputs this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 
18: character maps to <undefined>
```

I believe I need to "decode" the characters someway. How would this be accomplished?

Comment: it works just fine for me.

Comment: The error is for other parts of your code.

Comment: Please include the complete error message and mention which Python (2.7 or 3.x) you use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read Chinese files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486962/how-to-read-chinese-files)

Comment: You will have to identify the encoding the text file is using and give it to the `open()` function as the `encoding` argument. There are a few encodings for Chinese characters in use.

Comment: I am using Python 3.6

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it might helps you:

```
inputFile = open('chinchars.txt', encoding="utf8").readlines()
```

Note that it is better to open a file with `with`. like this:

```
with open('chinchars.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    inp = f.readlines()
```

Comment: @DyZ yes, that is why I wrote this might help you.

Comment: @DyZ I'm pretty sure the default for text streams (`sys.std*`, `open`) is locale/platform-dependent in Python 3. The encoding defaults to UTF-8 only for source encoding and for `str.encode/decode`.

Comment: @Elliptica, take a look at this link, it will answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662894/what-is-the-difference-between-read-and-readline-in-python#:~:text=The%20main%20difference%20is%20that,you%20specify%20in%20the%20parenthesis.